# /_api/web/features

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, feature

This applied to a site collection like `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/features`

retrieves a list of features ACTIVATED at the current scope.

1. Does that mean site collection features or site features or all?
2. Is there a way to find out deactivated features other than comparing list of active ones against a table of SPO available features?

Comment: For your first question, I sampled 10 random features from my list, and they all came back as web scoped features.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting the same results, but since I am having some issues with features in general, I wasn't sure if that's the correct behaviour. Any idea how I can check the site collection (Site Scope) features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `_api` you specify web which is the `SPWeb`. To get the site collection features, you can instead use `_api/site/features` to get the `SPSite` features.

The full list of features for on-prem is usually retrieved via `Get-SPFeature`, but that requires Shell Admin Access which would be unavailable in SharePoint Online. The feature IDs should be the same across sites, but you'll have to manually create the list of features to check against.